# How I can remove a <li> on <ul> which I added via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two  lists, one of which is empty. When I clicked the items of the not empty list I  deleted this and be added to the other. The problem is that the items I add to the list, if I click on them I can not delete and move it to the original list. I add the code.

This is HTML code

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="seleccion">

</ul>

<ul class="list-unstyled" id="categorias">
    <li>Subcategoría</li>
    <li id="494">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> 
        <a> Mujer</a>
    </li>                                   
    <li id="553">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> 
        <a>Hombre</a>
    </li>                                   
</ul>
```

And this is jQuery code:

```
$("#categorias li a").click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).text();
    var badge = $('<li>',{class:"categorias"}).append($('<i>',{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"})).append($('<a>',{text:texto}));
    $('#seleccion').append(badge);
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#seleccion li").click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).text();
    var tipo = $(this).attr('class');
    var badge = $("<li>").append($('<i>',{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-plus-  sign"})).append($('<a>',{text:texto}));
    $('#'+tipo).append(badge);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

ut
Example, when I clicked on 'Mujer' the element moves to the first ul, but if I clicked this I can remove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/64Ld2/?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#seleccion li a", function(){
```

Instead of `$("#seleccion li").click(function(){`

Comment: Thanks, as could be so simple? Thank you very much

Comment: @monchyrcg This is because the listener to the items of the second list was added BEFORE any item was actually added, therefore, it didn't work. The technique described in this answer is called "Delegation"